# Requested unknown parameter '4' for row 0 in datatable

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am getting the above error while trying to run a data table using jQuery DataTables library.

> Requested unknown parameter '4' for row 0.

```
<div class="container">
<%= render :partial => "layouts/society_nav" %>
<div align="center">
        <h3>Self Help Groups</h3>
</div>
        <%=link_to "New Self Help Groups" ,new_admin_self_help_group_path,:class=>"btn btn-primary btn-new"%>

<table class="datatable table-bordered"> 
    <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <% @selfhelp.each do |s|  %>
        <tr>
            <td class="thead">No of SHGS</td>
            <td colspan="2"><%= s.no_of_shgs %></td>
            <td> <%= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>".html_safe,  edit_admin_self_help_group_path(s) %>
            </td>
            <td> <%= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>".html_safe,  admin_self_help_group_path(s), :method => :delete, :title => "Delete?", "data-confirm" => "Do you really want to delete?" %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="thead">Out of which No of Women SHG</td>
            <td colspan="2"><%= s.no_of_women_shgs %></td>
            <td> <%= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>".html_safe,  edit_admin_self_help_group_path(s) %>
            </td>
            <td> <%= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>".html_safe,  admin_self_help_group_path(s), :method => :delete, :title => "Delete?", "data-confirm" => "Do you really want to delete?" %> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

DataTables library doesn't support `colspan` in table body, see [this tech note](https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4).

> This error can occur if there is a `colspan` or `rowspan` in the `tbody` of the table, which is not supported by DataTables.

However DataTables fully supports `colspan` and `rowspan` in the table's header, assuming there is at least one unique `<th>` for each column, see [DataTables complex header example](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/14/datatables-and-colspan) for more details.